# R: Effective method for calculating logic AND among columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the "and" combination among each columns except first id column. I achieved it via two for loops. However, if for large column and row size, the following method becomes very slow. Is there any efficient for such

```
library(dplyr)
Input <- data_frame(id=1:4, c1=c(T,T,F,F), c2=c(T,F,F,F),c3=c(F,T,F,F))
    id    c1    c2    c3
  1  1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
  2  2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  3  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
  4  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

desired output is:

```
> Output
  id c1_c2 c1_c3 c2_c3
  1  1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  2  2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  3  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
  4  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

for-loop approach:

```
Output <- data_frame(id=Input$id)
colSize <- ncol(Input)
colnms <- colnames(Input)
for(i in 2:(colSize-1)){
 for (j in (i+1):colSize){
   name_i <- paste(colnms[i],colnms[j],sep="_")
   logic_and <- (Input[colnms[i]]&Input[colnms[j]])
   Output$name <- logic_and
   names(Output)[ncol(Output)] <- name_i
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `combn` from `base R`

```
Input[-1] <- do.call(cbind, combn(Input[-1], 2, FUN = function(x) list(x[1] & x[2])))
names(Input)[-1] <- combn(names(Input)[-1], 2, FUN = paste, collapse="-")
Input
# A tibble: 4 × 4
#     id `c1-c2` `c1-c3` `c2-c3`
#   <int>   <lgl>   <lgl>   <lgl>
#1     1    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
#2     2   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
#3     3   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
#4     4   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: hi @akrun, combn works well. do you know how to avoid column ci_cj if all are FALSE?

Comment: @HappyCoding You can use `m1 <- do.call(cbind, combn(Input[-1], 2, FUN = function(x)  {i1 <- x[1] & x[2]; colnames(i1) <- paste(names(x[1]), names(x[2]), sep="_"); list(if(any(i1)) i1 else NULL) }))`